# How to make SELECT query work when the table schema is upgraded with a new column?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, select

I'm working on a JavaScript project which has an existing database (and hence an existing schema).

To add a new feature I must add a new column to the table. This will store a property of objects of a class.

Currently there is a `SELECT` query in the project which queries a bunch of fields from the database table every time the application starts and then puts these obtained results into the various needed JavaScript objects.

So, now it looks like:

```
let FIELDS = "field1, field2, field3";
let query = "SELECT " + FIELDS + "FROM FOO_TABLE";
```

Somewhere else, this query is made whenever needed (usually after app restart).

I thought of changing it to:

```
let FIELDS = "field1, field2, field3, new_prop";
```

But it won't work as in the current table, such a table doesn't exist. (Maybe after next restart, things will work, but not the first time).

What is the workaround?
Also, please note that a silent change will be better than one that will *show* that this property is **new** to everyone who works on the file.

Comment: I'm probably missing something here, but why can't you just add the column to the database first, have a reasonable default value if an older version of the project inserts data to it (or the updated version reads from old data where new_prop was never set), and after the db is updated then go ahead and deploy the new feature?

Comment: `have a reasonable default value if the updated version reads from old data where new_prop was never set` this is what I want to know how.

Comment: The older version of the project will never have to read the **new** table, because a **new** table can be created only by the newer version of the application.

Comment: I can't add the column first, because that is how it works now. First read from db, create objects, if necessary (new object is created while app is used) add a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't just add the field into the query, that won't work, so you have 2 options.

1. Use exceptions/errors to work out if something goes wrong. I'm not an sqlite guru (in fact i've never used sqlite directly, always via API's as with ios dev.), but if you try to run a query containing a column name that is non-existent, something will error which you can capture, work out the error code/string and decide to re-run the query minus the bad column.

**This is not a good idea, its dirty and expensive. I've used exceptions to save dupe check query's in the past, but even that isn't the correct way to do things... but it does work**

1. The only "proper" way to do what you want is to first check if the column exists. In sqlite, i don't think there's a simply select command like there is in mysql. But you can use the [`PRAGMA table_info('table-name')`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) statement to get all columns, then check if your column exists prioir to running the query. This is the correct way to do things.

Having said that, if your working in a collaborative/team dev environment, you should have a much cleaner way of upgrading everyone in the group. So i'd be more tempted to address that issue of procedure rather than code my way around it.